# осуществить поиск по всем .js файлам на сайте

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Есть ли такая возможность осуществить поиск по всем .js файлам на сайте?
Не открывать каждый файл и искать в нём, а именно во всех валах .js?
Может расширение какое то есть для devtools?

Answer (score 0):

В DevTools есть поиск по всем файлам, его можно открыть комбинацией клавиш `Ctrl + Shift + F`, либо выбрав из меню инструментов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]